# Oracle time interval buckets

Tags: sql, if-statement, oracle11g, case

```
select TRANSACTION, comp_time, start_time, (comp_time - start_time) as DIFF from table
where start_time = trunc(sysdate)
```

I want to calculate from the DIFF value , how many of TRANSACTION are completed in less than 10 sec, 1 min and 15 min in the same sql statement.
I am very new to SQL.. may be we can use some if-else or some CASE condition.. 
After getting those count for each value, I need to calculate the percentage for each of them..

Suppose i have total 3000 TRANSACTIONs, out of that 1500 completed in less than 10 sec. So percentage will be 50%
Same thing for 1 min and 15 min as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for SQL Server:

```
with timecounts as (
    select count(case when datediff(ss, start_time, comp_time) <= 10 then transactionId end) as q10s,
           count(case when datediff(ss, start_time, comp_time) <= 60 then transactionId end) as q1m,
           count(case when datediff(mi, start_time, comp_time) <= 15 then transactionId end) as q15m,
           count(*) qTotal   
    from   table
    where  start_time = trunc(sysdate)
    )

select q10s,
       q1m,
       q15m,
       case when qTotal <> 0 then cast(q10s as float) / qTotal end as q10sPerc,
       case when qTotal <> 0 then cast(q1m as float) / qTotal end as q1mPerc,
       case when qTotal <> 0 then cast(q15m as float) / qTotal end as q15mPerc
from   TimeCounts
```

for oracle:

```
with timecounts as (
    select count(case when (comp_time - start_time) * 86400 <= 10 then transactionId end) as q10s,
           count(case when (comp_time - start_time) * 86400 <= 60 then transactionId end) as q1m,
           count(case when (comp_time - start_time) * 1440 <= 15 then transactionId end) as q15m,
           count(*) qTotal   
    from   myTable
    where  start_time = trunc(sysdate)
    )

select q10s,
       q1m,
       q15m,
       case when qTotal <> 0 then cast(q10s as float) / qTotal end as q10sPerc,
       case when qTotal <> 0 then cast(q1m as float) / qTotal end as q1mPerc,
       case when qTotal <> 0 then cast(q15m as float) / qTotal end as q15mPerc
from   TimeCounts
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. while running query it is showing datediff is invalid identifier. Can you please let me know is this right function?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Oracle Enterprise Edition 11g

Comment: Thank you so much Paul.  It worked fine for me as per my requirement.. Really it helped me a lot....

Answer (score 2):

A normalised-result Oracle version, using an analytic function to calculate the percentages.

```
with cte_durations as (
  select
    case when (comp_time - start_time) * 24 * 60 * 60 < 10 then '< 10 sec'
         when (comp_time - start_time) * 24 * 60 * 60 < 60 then '< 1 min'
         when (comp_time - start_time) * 24 * 60      < 15 then '< 15 min'
         else                                                   '>= 15 min'
    end duration_bucket
  from  table
  where    start_time = trunc(sysdate))
select   duration_bucket,
         count(*),
         100*ratio_to_report(count(*)) over () pct_of_total
from     cte_durations
group by duration_bucket
order by case duration_bucket         
           when '< 10 sec'  then 1
           when '< 1 min'   then 2
           when '< 15 min'  then 3
           when '>= 15 min' then 4
         end
/
```